# $\mathbf{x}\wedge \mathbf{w} =0$ iff $\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{x}\wedge \mathbf{w}' $

Tags: vector-spaces, exterior-algebra

It' pretty much as stated in the title. Looking for a proof of the statement that
$\mathbf{x}\wedge \mathbf{w} =0$ iff $\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{x}\wedge \mathbf{w}'$ where $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w}' \in V$ where $V$ is some $n$-dimensional vector space.

The backwards direction is clear to me, it's the forwards direction that's causing me the issue (although I think I'm just being dense and it's trivial). I have tried picking a basis for $V$,  say $ \{ \mathbf{e}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{e}_n \}$ and setting $\mathbf{e}_1=\mathbf{x}$ WLOG but not getting very far.

Comment: What do you mean by $\wedge$? I would expect it to be the exterior product but the expression $x\wedge w'$ does not lie in V.

Comment: Do you know how to write $\mathbf{w}$ in terms of the $\mathbf{e}_i$? Also, as Johnny El Curvas points out, $w \not\in V$.

Comment: That was something I was a bit confused about too. It should indeed be the exterior product. This is a problem I've been set to complete so not sure if it's been incorrectly stated. I guess it makes more sense if the vectors lie in the k-fold wedge product of V? @JohnnyElCurvas

Comment: To me it would seem natural to assume that the statement you want to prove is $x\wedge w=0$ iff $w=w'x$, where $w'$ is a scalar. I would need more context though...

Comment: I guess that $\mathbf{w}$ is simply a linear combination of the $\mathbf{e}_i$ since they form a basis for $V$. The context for this question is it's an intermittant step in the proof of Cramers rule using exterior algebras. @JohnnyElCurvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $x\neq 0$. Then, as you said, we can pick a basis $\{ x,e_{2},...,e_{n} \}$ for $V$. Writing $e_{1}=x$, the set $\{ e_{i}\wedge e_{j}\colon i<j \}$ is a basis for $\Lambda^{2}V$.

Now, write $w=w'x+\sum_{i>1}w_{i}e_{i}$. The exterior product $x\wedge w$ satisfies

$$
x\wedge w=w'(x\wedge x)+\sum_{i=2}^{n}w_{i}x\wedge e_{i}=\sum_{i=2}^{n}w_{i}e_{1}\wedge e_{i}.
$$

Since the vectors $e_{1}\wedge e_{2},...,e_{1}\wedge e_{n}$ are independent, we get $x\wedge w=0$ iff $w_{2}=...=w_{n}=0$, which is equivalent to $w=w'x$.

Hope this helps!